# Cast Object to List of Custom DTOs in java

Tags: java, json, casting

Here's the code:

```
Object obj = getUsers();

List<UserDTO> userDTOList = new ArrayList<UserDTO>();

userDTOList = (ArrayList<UserDTO>)obj;

for (UserDTO userDTO : userDTOList) {

   do some stuff with userDTO   

}
```

The signature of "getUsers()" is as below

```
List<UserDTO> getUsers();
```

getUsers returns a list of users and if I print the object(The variable obj here) I can see them.

The obj is actually a json response as below

> [{firstName=A,lastName=B,emailAddress=A.B@email.com},{firstName=C,lastName=D,emailAddress=C.D@email.com},{firstName=E,lastName=F,emailAddress=E.F@email.com}]

Now the problem I'm facing is:

After the casting when I'm iterating over the casted userDTOList I see all the individual userDTOs carry the same data though actually they are different as I can confirm when I print the object. It's like the first user information is getting copied to others.

As with the example above, the 3 userDTOs should carry individual user information, but I'm getting say firstName=A for the three DTOs.

Any idea how to fix this or what's going wrong here?

## getUsers/setUsers from another DTO

```
private List<UserDTO> s$user;

public List<UserDTO> getUsers() {
    return s$user;
}

public void sets$user(List<UserDTO> s$user) {
    this.s$user = s$user;
}
```

## UserDTO

```
    private String s$firstName;
private String s$lastName;
private String s$emailAddress;
```

and their getter/setters

All the DTOs are getting set from json parsing.

Comment: What means `I see all the individual userDTOs carry the same data though actually they are different as I can confirm when I print the object.' ? Can you explain it I can not understand it.

Comment: Individual userDTOs carry the same information like firstName, lastName etc. after I cast that. But as you can see from the obj value, all user related information is different.

Comment: You may need to post more code, your question is vague and lacks clarity. This question may be put on hold, if you do not provide a better understanding for the problem.

Comment: Please do not prefix your instance variables with `s$` that makes your code highly unreadable and it does not play well with JavaBean specifications.

Comment: Also, that is not a JSON response, as it is invalid...

Comment: I bet the problem happens when you're creating parsing your JSON and populating the DTOs

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying that not all items in the list are UserDtos? If so try:

```
Object obj = getUsers();
List<Object> userDtoList = (ArrayList<Object>) obj;

for (Object userDtoObject : userDtoList) {
    if (userDtoObject instanceof UserDto) {
        UserDto userDto = (UserDto) userDtoObject;

        // Do stuff with userDto...
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**

If you are getting a JSON response, you should not cast it, you should be using a library such as:

- [Google's GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
- [JSON-Lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: The items in the list are all userDTOs but the problem is individual userDTO attributes like firstname, lastname etc. are not correct.

Comment: Well, you would have to give us a look at what your `getUsers()` method looks like and your `UserDto` class...

Comment: Well, provided the details of getUsers and UserDTO class